# How to play music when specific button shows?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

i have this code under view did load:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CPOP MUSIC.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

And when the user press's a button named 'play' when they do this a animation play and [audioplayer stop]; is used and after the animation two buttons appear, replay and menu. How would I state in the code something like 'when button 'replay' and 'menu' show [audioplayer play];?? thanks I am a beginner so please take it easy, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to replay from audioPlayer you need to call

```
[audioplayer play]
```

You can go through [AVAudioPlayer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) to get in depth knowledge about AVAudioPlayer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i know that but how do I actually state when the buttons show to [audioplayer play]?